# Looking up information in matching rows of pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of pandas DataFrames like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(
{'Change': {0: 'C>T', 1: 'C>T', 2: 'C>T'},
 'Gene': {0: 'TIIId', 1: 'HRAS', 2: 'p53-3'},
 'Loc': {0: 110541232, 1: 534280, 2: 7577120}}
)
```

That looks like this:

```
    Loc Change  Gene
0   110541232   C>T TIIId
1   534280  C>T HRAS
2   7577120 C>T p53-3
```

And I would like to pull information from other DataFrames like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(
{'Change': {1: 'T>C', 342: 'A>T', 499: 'C>T', 556: 'C>T', 1082: 'C>T'},
 'Gene': {1: 'TIIIa', 342: 'SF3B1', 499: 'IDH1', 556: 'TIIIb', 1082: 'TIIId'},
 'Loc': {1: 115227854,
  342: 198266844,
  499: 209113142,
  556: 223190698,
  1082: 110541232},
 'VAF': {1: 0.0008172746042670338,
  342: 0.0005706242629436604,
  499: 0.0012779008348952122,
  556: 0.0011640569261387105,
  1082: 0.9980550801306987}}
)
```

That looks like this:

```
    Loc Change  VAF Change  Gene
1   115227854   T>C 0.000817275 T>C TIIIa
342 198266844   A>T 0.000570624 A>T SF3B1
499 209113142   C>T 0.0012779   C>T IDH1
556 223190698   C>T 0.00116406  C>T TIIIb
1082    110541232   C>T 0.998055    C>T TIIId
```

I would like to get all the values that fall under the `VAF` column for entries that have the same `Loc` and `Change` combination between the two DataFrames.

So in the provided example, I would like to get the value of `0.998055` because location `110541232` and Change `C>T` are found in both DataFrames.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2).VAF`

Comment: @user3483203 Ahh right, thanks.